# Using an array as an input for a multivariable function

Tags: python, numpy

If I have a multivariable function such as
`F= lambda x,y: x**2+y**2`
and if I need to use the input `x0=np.array([1,1])`

May I know how I should use `x0` to get the value from `F`?
I understand that I could use something like `F(x0[0],x0[1])`

But I would like to know whether there is a way that I can directly use `x0` rather than calling each cordinate manually

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python lets you do this by doing `F(*x0)`, which expands the array into the parameters. In other languages this is sometimes called "splatting".